# Topology where relative complement of open sets is empty or contains a nonempty open set

Tags: general-topology

Is there a standard name for a topology where every relative complement of an ordered pair of open sets is either empty or contains an open set?

---

My question is vaguely inspired by [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FtjHYnZv3So) about Grothendieck topologies. However, my question is much more basic than the contents of the video. I don't know much about topology or category theory, so please take the summary with a grain of salt; it's just meant to show where the question comes from.

In the initial example given of an open covering, we have a family of open sets $\mathcal{U}$ indexed by an index set $I$ such that $\cup_{i \in I} \mathcal{U}_i = U$. I think we're insisting on that stronger property rather than $\cup_{i \in I}\mathcal{U}_i \subset U$, but I don't know enough to say for sure. When this example was initially presented, I was wondering how we tell whether a given covering covers a set using machinery given to us by the category alone and not the original topological space.

Then I thought about properties some topologies might have, namely whether the relative complement of two open sets is either empty or contains a non-empty subset.

In the topology $\{\varnothing, \{1\}, \{0, 1\} \} $, the relative complement of $\{0, 1\}$ and $\{1\}$ is $\{0\}$, which is not open and has no open subsets except $\varnothing$.

In the standard topology on the reals $\mathbb{R}$, the relative complement of any ordered pair of open sets is either empty or contains a non-empty open set.

This seems like a really simple property for a topology to have or lack:

1. Does it have a name?
2. Does this property work for letting us express whether a given collection of objects is a covering for a particular set in entirely category-theoretic language?

For (2), I think we can argue that we can detect whether any given pair of open sets are disjoint, and therefore whether an open set is pairwise disjoint from a family of open sets. Then we say that if there is an open set $V$ that is a subset of $U$, but is pairwise disjoint from every $\mathcal{U}_i$, then $\mathcal{U}_i$ is not an open cover. ... So we can detect "spillover" in open cover by checking whether each $\mathcal{U}_i$ is a subset of $U$ and detect gaps by trying to "fit a pairwise distinct $V$" in between the cracks. I think that works.

Comment: This is an extremely strong and rare property for a topology to have.  The usual topology on the reals does not have it; for instance, consider the complement of $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Note that if $X$ has a closed subset $A$ with empty interior, then it cannot have this property. That's because if $A\subseteq U$ is open then $V=U\backslash A$ is open as well, however $U\backslash V=A$ does not contain nonempty open subset. In particular this excludes non-discrete $T_1$ spaces because these have at least one closed, but not open point. And that automatically excludes like 99% of topology we typically deal with. Yeah, its extremely rare.